# Case decision if I declared a Class

Tags: r, r-s4

How could I ask R if the class I declared is my class? What I want to do is, if I have a character vector like `a<-c("vector","MyClass")` I want to write a case decission if that class is written by my self or from a different package?

```
setClass(Class = "MyClass",
         representation = representation(name = "character",
                                         type = "character"
                                         )
         )
```

Or how to ask if the class exists in certain namespace?

Comment: Is the idea here that you want a function `is.MyClass(a)` that will return `TRUE`?

Comment: @gung Yes but more general, that means isOneOfMyClasses(a) should return TRUE.